# Unable to install Python library in Kaggle notebook

Tags: python, kaggle

When I run `!pip install 'library_name'`  in the kaggle console it throws this warning:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('
<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc7bd22aed0>:
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
')': /simple/pip/
```

and ultimately doesn't install the library.

What is the reson for this warning and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Open the tab bar on the right -> In the Settings drop-down, enable 'Internet'. Now you can install any python library.

Answer (score 4):

In case the internet option is not visible, you must confirm your phone number. Kaggle requires your phone number to be verified when you first register in order for you to use certain functions, such internet access.

Another source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68142525/8654414

Comment: Thank you very much, it was obvious for those who read manuals :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Yash has already answered. I got the option to enable Internet under 'Notebook Option':

[image]