# Cannot access internet on Kaggle Notebook

Tags: kaggle

The error I got that prompted this question is this:

`URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`

which occurred when I ran the command `pd.read_csv(url)` on a Kaggle notebook.

Turns out the problem was that internet access was not enabled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Make sure your Kaggle account is phone verified by clicking "Get phone verified" and following the steps

[image: Kaggle settings menu before phone verification]

2. After phone verification, the full settings menu should be visible. Toggle the "Internet" switch.

[image]

3. Done

Answer (score 4):

Update 26/03/23

It's under `Notebook Options` in the right hand column

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is no longer an issue as internet is on by default now: https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/product-feedback/138355

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue while using Kaggle, ultimately because I did not perform phone number verification and after verification, I needed to open the "Internet on" button in the Notebook option. This button is not available when phone number verification is not performed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfuYG.png)